# Why does different antenna inductivity influence LF-RFID performance?

Tags: inductance, rfid

I'm experimenting with LF (125kHz) RFID reader antenna design. And trying two different antennas yields very different results in terms of read sensitivity. Even though one antenna is driven with considerably more current it performs worse. And I'd like to know why :-)

For all test setups:
45mm Antenna inner diameter, same carrier for coil, same RFID tag.
Resonance capacitor adjusted to within 1kHz target frequency. Voltage divider on Antenna demodulation unchanged (same sensitivity of ~37mV).

**Antenna test setup 1:**

- 0.75 mH, 0.22mm wire diameter
- 9.7 Ohm @ 100kHz
- Added series resistance of 33 Ohm to get a Q-factor of ~15
- resulting drive current: ~130mA
- resulting drive voltage: ~83V
- magnetic field strength: ~1.86mT
- *read range: ~2cm*

**Antenna test setup 2:**

- 2.66 mH @ 100kHz , 0.1mm wire diameter
- 77.2 Ohm @ 100kHz
- Added series resistance of 82 Ohm to get a Q-factor of ~15
- resulting drive current: ~38mA
- resulting drive voltage: ~91V
- magnetic field strength: ~1.23mT
- *read range: ~5cm*

Comment: More inductance means more turns of wire, right?

Comment: Yep, ~80 turns on coil 1, ~180 turns on coil 2

Comment: The magnetic field strength is proportional to the current multiplied by the number of turns.

Comment: @DaveTweed I've added the magnetic field strength for my antenna, and Setup 1 still comes out on top. On paper that is, is real world performance that different from the calculations that magnetic field strength is still the best explanation?